# Combining tables using python in databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, join, merge, databricks

I have 3 tables:

Table 1 df contains the following columns

- `user_id` for a person's unique member id
- `order_dt` which contains dates, and
- `order_sequence` which contains user milestones

For example if user 'AA' registered on '2/2/2022' `order_sequence` would show 'REGISTERED'

```
User_id Order_dt    Order_sequence
------------------------------------
AA      2/2/2022    REGISTERED
BB      2/3/2022    REGISTERED
BB      4/8/2022    O1
```

Table 2 df_mh contains 2 columns member_id which matches user_id from temp_df and source_id which is also a unique ID but different from member ID. For example user AA would show AA from member_id and ZZ for source id

```
Member_id   Source_id
---------------------
AA           ZZ
BB           UU
CC           VV
```

Table 3 df_cs contains 3 columns CONSUMER_UPM_ID which matches source_id from df_mh created_date  which contains dates and purpose which contains string text.

```
CONSUMER_UPM_ID Created_Date  PURPOSE
---------------------------------------
  ZZ             3/5/2022     EXP1
  UU             6/8/2022     EXP1
  LL             5/3/2022     EXP2
```

I would like to combine the information from table 3 with table 1 by adding corresponding UPM_ID's to table 1 from table 3 and add their 'created_date' values to the 'order_dt' column and their 'purpose' values to the 'order_sequence' column

Example output

```
User_id UPM ID  Order_dt    Order_sequence
------------------------------------------
AA      ZZ      2/2/2022    REGISTERED
AA      ZZ      3/5/2022    EXP1
BB      UU      2/3/2022    REGISTERED
BB      UU      4/8/2022    O1
BB      UU      6/8/2022    EXP1
```

and as a next step I want to add a condition that only adds new rows from table 3 if the created_date is within a year of the users registered date

I originally came up with this

```
# Perform the first join between temp_df and temp_df_mh to get UPM_IDs
joined_df = temp_df.join(temp_df_mh, temp_df.user_id == temp_df_mh.member_id, "left")

# Perform the second join to add additional information from temp_df_cs
final_df = joined_df.join(temp_df_cs, joined_df.source_id == temp_df_cs.CONSUMER_UPM_ID, "left")

# Update the order_dt column with created_date values and order_sequence column with purpose values
final_df = final_df.withColumn("order_dt", when(final_df.created_date.isNull(), final_df.order_dt).otherwise(final_df.created_date))
final_df = final_df.withColumn("order_sequence", when(final_df.purpose.isNull(), final_df.order_sequence).otherwise(final_df.purpose))

# Select the desired columns in the final output
output_df = final_df.select("user_id", "source_id", "order_dt", "order_sequence")

# Show the resulting DataFrame
output_df.show()
```

but Im not adding new rows, just replacing values which is not what I am trying to do, thanks for the help!